# VSTO Outlook: Change font color for some email addresses (To) in compose window

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have an VSTO Outlook Addin and I would like to know how can I change the font color of some email addresses (To:) in the compose window. Is that possible? If so how?

I want to avoid using custom form regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that.

The best what you could do is to create [a form region based on the replacement layout](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0e56d3ec-2037-4361-9d4c-6f911b555981/how-to-create-replacement-or-replaceall-outlook-form-regions?forum=vsto) which substitutes the built-in controls. Be aware, you need to implement all the fields on your own in that case. A replacement form region is a page that replaces the default page of a standard form, and a replace-all form region replaces all pages in a standard Outlook form. See [Walkthrough: Design an Outlook form region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-designing-an-outlook-form-region?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.

Comment: Okay but if I create a form region associated with a standard class (Mail Message IPM.Note), the form region inherits all the controls and objects that there are in the compose window? I mean, To, From, cc, bcc/cco, body, etc. So then I can override the look and feel for the "To" field in order to I can colored some email addresses? Do I also have to handle all the events on those fileds? It seems very complicated and also doing this if Outlook look and feel changes, custom form region does not change automatically, this is the problem when using form regions. I am very newbie in VSTO Outlook.

Comment: There is no trivial way for getting that done. No, you will not be able to handle standard events if you replace fields with a form region. You can use your controls' event in that case. Also you may find [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php) helpful.

Comment: And what if I subscribe to lost focus event on email address ("To" Field) and after each email address is typed in I then change its text from for example "example@gmail.com" to a one using html format and applying an style like "<html><body><span style="color:red">example@gmail.com</span></body></html>". Will Outlook parse it correctly as html and then show it in red?

Comment: Okay, maybe there are some other easy alternatives rather than replace entire inspector window with a custom form region... I could mark those emails with an asterisk symbol. How could I mark some recipients with an asterisk after they are entered in the "TO" field? Also I would need to remove the asterisk from the email addresses before sending it.... How can achieve this?